# Como almacenar varias instancias de Persona en un solo txt (Binario)

Tags: java

tengo un problema con mi codigo, todo funciona correctamente. Pero quiero que al momento de que llenen el formulario este se guarde en un txt (Esto logro hacerlo) pero cuando quieren agregar a otra persona no se guarda, si no que se remplaza y aparece el ultimo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi JTable, aqui lo que hago es leer lo almacenado en el txt. Punto importante el txt esta en binario.

```
private void guardarMedico() {
        
        String primerNombre = iFrame.getTxtPrimeNombre().getText();
        String segundoNombre= iFrame.getTxtSegundoNombre().getText();
        String primerApellido = iFrame.getTxtPrimeApellido().getText();
        String segundoApellido = iFrame.getTxtSegundoApellido().getText();
        String edad = iFrame.getTxtEdad().getText();
        String cedula = iFrame.getTxtCedula().getText();
        String telefono = iFrame.getTxtTelefono().getText();
        Especialidad especialidad = (Especialidad) iFrame.getCmbEspecialidad().getSelectedItem();
        String anio = iFrame.getTxtAnioExperiencia().getText();
        String mes = iFrame.getTxtMesExperiencia().getText();
        String calle = iFrame.getTxtCalle().getText();
        String ciudad = iFrame.getTxtCiudad().getText();
        String numero = iFrame.getTxtNumero().getText();
        String licencia = iFrame.getTxtLicencia().getText();
        Direccion direccion = new Direccion(ciudad,calle,numero);
        Excepciones e = new Excepciones(primerNombre,segundoNombre,primerApellido,segundoApellido,cedula);
        e.carnet();
        String carnet = e.getCarnet();
        Persona p  = new Medico(direccion,primerNombre,segundoNombre,primerApellido,segundoApellido,edad,telefono,cedula,carnet,licencia,especialidad,anio,mes,4,5);
        List<Persona> lstPersona = new ArrayList<Persona>();
        lstPersona.add(p);
        guardarLista(lstPersona);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
```

Este es mi metodo guardarMedico aqui lo que hago es acceder a cada TextField, almacenarlo en un atributo y a estos atributos ponerlos en una instancia luego creo una lista de personas ,agrego la instancia a la lista y la guardo en un txt.

```
public static void guardarLista(List<Persona> lstPersona) {
          try {
           ObjectOutputStream objSalida = 
            new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src/formularioMedico.txt"));
           objSalida.writeObject(lstPersona);
           objSalida.close();
           System.out.println("Archivo guardado");
          } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Este es mi metodo guardarLista aqui lo que hago es recibir la lista creada antes y la convierto a un archivo binario txt. Ahora mi problema es que cuando quiero agregar a otra persona, simplemente  no se mantiene el contenido del txt sino que se remplaza por la nueva instancia. Existe forma de almacenar varias instancias de Persona en un solo txt.

Comment: Se me ocurren 2 maneras: 1) Debes guardar la lista entera de médicos, si te fijas en tu código creas una lista nueva y guardas un solo médico. Dicho de otro forma, debes mantener la lista completa de médicos, al guardar agregas a la lista y la guardas en el fichero (sin crear una nueva lista). 2) La otra es buscar la posición de lo escrito en el fichero y agregarlo después de esta (este método sé que existe pero no te sabría decir como implementarlo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu problema tiene fácil solución simplemente tienes que añadir el parámetro `true` a tu `FileOutputStream` esto hará que cuando crees el archivo no sobreescriba la nueva información sobre la anterior sino que la añada al final.
te quedaría tal que así:

```
new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src/formularioMedico.txt", true));
```